# Lua: 'for' loop problems (string.gsub)

Tags: lua

I'm making a lua script for custom encrypting a string, but I can't find a loop that substitutes the letter to a number correspondent to the alphabet table. 
   It must return something like this:

```
  "hello"
> 8, 4, 12, 12, 15
```

That'll be the first part of the encryption proccess but I can't program such a loop, any help? (Script below:)

```
local text = "what"

local key = math.random(100000, 500000) 
local pie = math.pi 
local n = 26

local alpha = { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6 , g = 7, h = 8, i = 9, j = 10, 
k = 11, l = 12, m = 13, n = 14, o = 15, p = 16, q = 17, r = 18, s = 19, t = 20, u = 21, v = 22, w = 23, x = 24, y = 25, z = 26} 


function enumerate(str) 
 return str:gsub("%l", function(c) return c.char(c:byte()-96) end):byte(1,-1) 
end
```

---

**UPDATE:** New question, how do I return the numbers as:

```
46, 68, 46, 32, 4, 12, 18, 15, 23, 32, 15, 23, 5, 8
```

Instead of a *string* or with *whitespaces*:

```
"46 68 46 32 4 12 18 15 23 32 15 23 5 8"
```

Comment: Function `string.byte(str, 1, -1)` may be useful.

Comment: `function crypto(str) return str:gsub("%l", function(c) return c.char(c:byte()-96) end):byte(1,-1) end` Usage: `print(crypt("hello"))`

Comment: One more question (Sorry I'm a beggineer on this kind of advanced scripting), what should I do to convert the numbers resulted into separate entrys, like   8, 5, 23, 15    (not as a string) so I can do the rest of the math?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff would you please answer question using answers, not comments. that's some ugly habit of yours. ;)

Comment: @Piglet - "comment" is my middle name ;-)

Comment: Regarding your update: `print(table.concat({enumerate('hello')},', '))`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to collect each char on a table with explode + encode (see below) and then call unpack (or table.unpack) to get a tuple.

First explode:

```lua
function explode(str)
    local ret = {}
    for c in str:gmatch(".") do 
        table.insert(ret, c)
    end
    return ret 
end
```

The encoding part can be done this way:

```
local BASE_CHAR = ("a"):byte()

function encode(c) 
    return c:byte() - BASE_CHAR + 1
end
```

Putting everything together:

```
unpack = unpack or table.unpack -- Handling lua 5.1 or higher

function enumerate(str) -- Keeping the original name
    local exploded = {}
    for i, c in ipairs(explode(str)) do
        exploded[i] = encode(c)
    end
    return unpack(exploded)
end
```

And a test:

```
print(enumerate("test"))
```

Which yields the following result:

```
20      5       19      20
```

Note:

I prefer to keep results in table and only unpack if necessary. This way you can manipulate the table the way you want and it's more convenient than dealing with tuples:

```
function enumerate(str) -- Keeping the original name
    local exploded = {}
    for i, c in ipairs(explode(str)) do
        exploded[i] = encode(c)
    end
    return exploded
end

print(unpack(enumerate("test")))
```

And if you want a string:

```
print(table.concat(enumerate("test"), ", "))
```

Hope this solves the problem

Comment: _:41: attempt to call local 'exploded' (a table value)_

That's weird, I don't see any problem on your code but the compiler returns this error.

Comment: Just tryed here with Lua 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3. All worked well. Did you copy the code or retyped into your editor? This error implies that you are calling `exploded(....)` somewhere.

Comment: I'm running this on 'repl.it' for convenience reasons, and on my code it isn't calling `exploded()` anywhere else. Ask me if you need a link to the entire code.